# Algorithm for incrementing numbers in each position in an array

Tags: algorithm

I wonder if there is a formal name for this algorithm and what is an elegant way to solve this: the problem is -- given an array, say, `[3, 6, 2]`, print out all the numbers starting with `000`, `100`, `200`, `300`, then the next number will "carry over" and become `010`, and then `110`.  It is like the odometer of a car, except it is fine to increase the digit at the other end instead.  The `6` is the maximum number for the second digit.  The `2` is the maximum number for the third digit.  So the program should print out `362` as the last number.

I came up with the solution below, but it looks too messy.  So I wonder if there is an elegant solution, and does this problem and solution actually have a formal name and a known elegant solution for solving it?

Recursion actually is possible, but I think if the recursion returns an array of all the numbers, the algorithm won't be able to handle it if the input array has 10 or 15 numbers in it, because the resulting array can grow exponentially and it can become really big and eat up a lot of memory.

```
# In Ruby

def print_all_numbers(arr_ranges)
  arr = arr_ranges.map { 0 }   # convert it to [0, 0, 0]

  while (true)
    incrementer_index = 0
    puts arr.join
    arr[incrementer_index] += 1
    while arr[incrementer_index] > arr_ranges[incrementer_index]
      arr[incrementer_index] = 0
      incrementer_index += 1
      return if incrementer_index >= arr.length 
      arr[incrementer_index] += 1
    end
  end
end

print_all_numbers([3, 6, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is simpler, in my opinion.  Make the function take the list of digit maxima and a suffix containing the digits computed so far.  If the list is empty. the suffix is the number to print.  Otherwise, peel the last maximum off the list and iterate, calling yourself recursively.  I don't know Ruby.  Here's a (tested) Python solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def printNumbers(digitMaxima, suffix=''):
    if len(digitMaxima) == 0:
        print suffix
        return

    thisDigitMaximum = digitMaxima[-1]
    remainingDigitMaxima = digitMaxima[:-1]
    for d in range(0, thisDigitMaximum+1):
        digitAsString = '%d' % d
        printNumbers(remainingDigitMaxima, digitAsString + suffix)

printNumbers([3, 6, 2])
```

Comment: so you use recursion, but you don't return all the possible numbers, but just strip out 1 number (and loop through its possibilities), and reduce the array and recurse... that's interesting technique, I don't usually recurse this way... is there a name for this technique?

Comment: (I think your solution would need the `range(0, thisDigitMaximum + 1)`)

Comment: There's no special name for the technique.  You are right about the range.  I didn't read your question carefully enough.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is mixed-base (or Mixed Radix) positional numeral system. Well-known example - hours-minutes-seconds. You can walk through all the values with simple cycle.
Precalculate partial products of radixes and use integer division and modulus operation to isolate every digit.

Example for decimal system: to extract the fourth digit of 76543, we use (76543 div 1000) mod 10.

Working Delphi code

```
var
  A, Products: TDynIntegerArray;
  Len, i, j: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  A := TDynIntegerArray.Create(3, 4, 2);
  Len := Length(A);
  SetLength(Products, Len);
  Products[Len - 1] := 1;
  for i := Len - 2 downto 0  do
    Products[i] := Products[i + 1] * (A[i + 1] + 1); //partial products
  for i := 0 to Products[0] * (A[0] + 1) - 1 do begin // overall count of "numbers"
    s := '';
    for j := 0 to Len - 1 do
      s := s + IntToStr((i div Products[j]) mod (A[j] + 1));
    Memo1.Lines.Add(s); // output string
  end;
```

Output:
000
001
002
010
011
012
020
021
022
030
031
032
040
041
042
100
101
102
110
111
112
120
121
122
130
131
132
140
141
142
200
201
202
210
211
212
220
221
222
230
231
232
240
241
242
300
301
302
310
311
312
320
321
322
330
331
332
340
341
342

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific language in mind? Python has a [`range()` method](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html) which makes problems like this fairly simple. `range(n)` returns a list of all numbers between `0` and `n-1`, so `range(3)` returns `[0, 1, 2]`. Some light Googling tells me that a similar effect can be created in Ruby [using `(0..n-1)`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_ranges.htm) (although this seems a bit hackish).

Using `range()`, I'd then take a dynamic programming approach to the problem where I store all the possible prefixes for the digits I've seen (starting with no prefix). I would iterate over each maximum number, calculate all the possible valid numbers, then combine these with the valid prefixes, resulting in a new list of valid prefixes that is 1 digit longer than the previous list. Once my "prefix" is as long as the desired number I am finished.

For example, given `[1, 2, 3]`, first I generate `[0, 1]` (all the valid digits for a maximum of 1). Next I generate `[0, 1, 2]` (all the valid digits for a maximum of 2) and then combine these with my list of possible prefixes (`[0, 1]`) to generate `[00, 01, 02, 10, 11, 12]`. This is now my new list of prefixes and I repeat until I have looked at all the maxiumum values. All without the need for recursion. I also feel this solution is a bit easier to understand both conceptually and looking at the code.

Here is a Python implementation:

```
def printNumbers(maxNums):
    possibleNums = [""] #start with empty prefix

    for digit in maxNums: #start with the first digit then work back
        possibleSuffixes = range(digit + 1) #+1 to allow us to capture the number itself

        newNums = [] #this will hold the new list of possible numbers
        for prefix in possibleNums: #looking at each prefix
            for suffix in possibleSuffixes: #looking at each suffix
                newNums.append("{}{}".format(prefix, suffix)) #join them
        possibleNums = newNums

    for num in possibleNums: #for each number
        print num
```

*Note that instead of `"{}{}".format()` I could have used string concatenation but since I am combining `str`s and `int`s I wanted to avoid any type errors*